# Alternatives to the Kruskal-Wallis test?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, cluster-sample

I have determined malaria prevalence in 8 villages with household-level clustering.

As an initial test (basic descriptive statistics), what test (as the independence assumption of K-W is violated) is appropriate for determining a statistically significant difference in prevalence between the villages?

Comment: It sounds like you need a more complex model that includes *Household* along with *Village*.  (The structure is not clear to me in the question.).  A nonparametric model like *aligned ranks transformation anova* might address this situation.  But also, you might look at *mixed effects model* or *generalized linear model*, perhaps in the form of ordinal regression.  ... You might need to describe more the structure of your data, and  how *Prevalence* is *being* measured.

Comment: Hi Sal, thanks for your response. In the later analysis, I plan on using (as you say) a mixed effects model with household as a random intercept and village as a fixed effect. What I am looking for is a simple statistical test in the early stages of descriptive statistics - I want a test that can indicate if there is a difference in prevalence (measured simply as the proportion infected) between the villages in this first instance - but the clustering rules out K-W. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe designing a [constrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)) will obtain the desired test.

Comment: I don't know why you want an initial test before fitting your model.  Why not just run the desired model ?  You certainly could present summary statistics that ignore the effect of Household, but you should be able to get output from your mixed effects model that will better present the e.g. mean for each Village.

Comment: Hi Sal, thanks. In the final model, the outcome will be the prevalence of infection at the individual level. I am performing a risk factor analysis of the individual and household-level risk factors for malaria infection. In the descriptive part, I have a map of the villages on which I want to show the village-level prevalence. Also, a table showing village-level prevalence. This test I want is just to show (what I expect to be) a significant difference. I will do the same for each covariate using the adjusted chi-square test. This is all before building the mixed model. Thanks

Comment: I thought the Friedman test might be appropriate, but that is for repeated measures. I was not sure if that was appropriate in this context.

Comment: It doesn't sound like your structure matches Friedman test.

Comment: The reason I want to perform the initial test is that I am not actually testing village-level differences in the main model. Yet, it is still interesting and relevant to the overall discussion. It is the only opportunity I have to show a statistically significant difference. A similar paper used K-W to do the same thing, but I think wrongly so, as the clustering violated the independence assumption of K-W. I might have to report the prevalence without a test, and jump straight to the main model as you suggest. Thanks

Comment: Genrally, I would avoid adding hypothesis tests (a form of inferential statistics) to a section of descriptive statistics.

Comment: Simple descriptive statistics and initial oversimplified analyses have negative value when they do not match the data structure / study design.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, @Alexis. I might have been making the mistake of just copying what has been done in the previous paper I am using as a model. Certainly makes things easier too.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments. Very informative.